# Error rebuild all index by procedure ORA-01450: maximum key length

Tags: indexing

im having some problems to rebuild all normal indexes by a procedure, the error code are:

ORA-01450: maximum key length (3215) exceeded
ORA-06512: on line 11
ORA-06512: on line 11
01450. 00000 -  "maximum key length (%s) exceeded"

This is my script:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
    
FOR index_entry IN (select * from user_indexes 
                where index_type='NORMAL')
    LOOP
        IF (SUBSTR(index_entry.INDEX_NAME,LENGTH(index_entry.INDEX_NAME), 1)) = '$' THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Error en: ' || index_entry.INDEX_NAME);
        
    ELSE
              dbms_output.put_line('ALTER INDEX ' || index_entry.INDEX_NAME || ' REBUILD ONLINE NOLOGGING'); 
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || index_entry.INDEX_NAME || ' REBUILD ONLINE NOLOGGING';
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Do you have any idea how could I rebuild all normal indexes and avoid this ORA?, i mean if find any normal index with maximum key length ignore it, continue and finish rebuilding all indexes?